# RT doesn't distinguish between 'correspondence request-user' and 'replays from CCs to a internal comment'

Tags: configuration, rt, ticket-tracking

I'm in IT support. We have two types of correspondence:

1. **With final users**. The usual external communication with them.
2. **With service providers** (DBA, etc) Internal communication that *can't be seen for the requestors*.

For the first one, we use the 'answer to requestor'.

For the service providers, we use a comment and send CC to the service provider. But when they reply, RT considers their reply as correspondence and execute the actions for the 'correspondence' condition.

Then, when i wanna customize the scrips, RT doesn't distinguish between the actions: an email to the user and a replay from the provider (internal CC) are both "on correspondence" for RT, and **send them both to the requestor**.

I don't realize how to configure RT for send 1 y 2 to different actions.

Have I configurated something wrong? Which must I consider?
Or must I use a custom user scrip?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RT should do what you are expecting, which is send correspondence (replies) to the requestor and send comments only to staff. There are two areas to look at to sort out why this isn't happening:

1) By default, RT's notification scrips use the Cc role to add another requestor. If you want to add a "commenter," you want to use the AdminCc role rather than Cc. This is likely the problem.

2) If that doesn't fix it, make sure you have two email addresses set up, one for correspondence and one for comment, something like support@example.com (correspond address) and support-comment@example.com (comment address). Then make sure you have your /etc/aliases file set up to route correspond with --action correspond and comment with --action comment. An initial example is provided in step 10 in the [RT README](https://bestpractical.com/docs/rt/4.2/README.html).

Comment: Hi, Jim, thanks for your answer. Is, at first and without testing yet, very useful, because our RT has only one email address for the two functions (2) and we weren't using the ccAdmin either (1).

I had read the O'Reilly manual and all the online documentation, but no this README. I just read it.

Thank you. I'll test and comment again.